# Empty patch name is not legal

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Это код загрузки изображения в базу данных MySQL:

```
 private void v_add_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] imageBt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.img_patch.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

        string constring = "datasource=localhost; port=3306;username=root;password=password";
        string Query = "insert into database_name.table_name (name, owner, type, imo, built_year, builder, flag, mmsi, call_sign, gross_weight, info_addi, img) values ('" + this.name_txt.Text + "', '" + this.owner_combo.Text + "', '" + this.type_txt.Text + "', '" + this.imo_txt.Text + "',  '" + this.byear_txt.Text + "', '" + this.builder_txt.Text + "','" + this.flag_txt.Text + "', '" + this.mmsi_txt.Text + "',  '" + this.callsign_txt.Text + "',  '" + this.gross_txt.Text + "','" + this.additional_txt.Text + "', @IMG   ); ";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);

        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imageBt));
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader(); 
            MessageBox.Show("users saved");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
```

Все работает, но если я не хочу загружать изображение, выдает ошибку

> "Empty patch name is not legal"

Как сделать, чтобы я мог добавить в базу что-то без изображения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

patch я у вас в коде не нашел, но

> "Empty path name is not legal"

выдает при попытке создать FileStream с пустой строкой вместо имени файла, возможно что ошибка здесь:

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.img_patch.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

а не при загрузке в базу данных. В таком случае, вероятно надо вынести в отдельную функцию код

```
byte[] imageBt = null;
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.img_patch.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
```

в которой будет осуществляться кроме того проверка валидности пути